# Browser extension - copying website source to a clipboard on click. I want to get source after javascript is executed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I can't find the solution to this.

Imagine scenario:

You are entering LinkedIn, doing some search and then running browser extension to copy to clipboard actual source of the website - the same code as you can see at a right mouse click and Inspect.

Is this possible? 
Is there already any solution to that?

Comment: `document.documentElement.innerHTML`

Comment: Did you try the code in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the HTML of the entire document using

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

and then [copy that string to the clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript):

```
const { outerHTML } = document.documentElement;
const textarea = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('textarea'));
textarea.value = outerHTML;
textarea.focus();
textarea.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
textarea.remove();
```